# Confirm Delete Not Work

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have one link for buy credit . i want when click on link confirm show so if user click yes link direct . but in my page when i click yes or no link direct me to href link . means yes or no not difrent and link work.

```
    <script>
    <!--
    function confirmbuy() {
    if (confirm("Are You Sure???")) {
    return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
<a href="buy.php" onclick="confirmbuy();">Buy</a>
```

i test this code for submit button and work propertly but for link not work !!!

Comment: You should get rid of the `<!--`, there is no need to protect Netscape 2 era browsers this century.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event handler function (defined by the value of the intrinsic event attribute) doesn't return anything. It just calls `confirmbuy` and then stops.

If you want to return the return value of `confirmbuy` then you must do so explicitly:

```
onclick="return confirmbuy();">
```

You wouldn't have this problem is `confirmbuy` was the event handler:

```
ref_to_link.addEventListener('click', confirmbuy);
```

I recommend reading more about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the result of the `confirmbuy()` function, otherwise the event will never be cancelled.

```
<a href="buy.php" onclick="return confirmbuy();">Buy</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline handlers are actually put into a function, which is set as the handler for the click event. So basically your code is equivalent to:

```
a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    confirmbuy();
})
```

As you can see, this handler does not return false, so the event progresses as normal.

Answer (score 1):

you need:

```
onclick="return confirmbuy();"
```

Answer (score 1):

better..

```
<a href="buy.php" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure???');">Buy</a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call *reducing* the seperation of concerns "better".

Answer (score 1):

Fixed and removed unnecessary code:

```
<a href="buy.php" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure???');">Buy</a>
```

Comment: You'll need to alternate your quotes

Comment: Not going to try steal the credit... it was [@GBD that fixed it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13379599/revisions) ;).